# How to Combine Two Image Overlaying Into One Image in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, image

I have two images of different sizes. I can make them overlay each other using `Map.addLayer()` for each. But I want to combine them into one image as shown in illustration below. How to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Never mind my impatience,

It was easy. I just convert them to image collection and then create mosaic of it!

```
var combined_img = ee.ImageCollection([img_1, img_2]).mosaic();
```

Comment: Well done on answering your question!  A good answer should not only include what, but also how you go about solving the problem.  Please [edit] your answer to also include the steps required to perform your solution.

Comment: Okay, I did edit it now